# enabling telegraf system input plugin on OpenBSD 6.5

Tags: openbsd, telegraf

https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/inputs/system

Could use some examples. I have tried adding values listed in the above page to

```
[[inputs.system]]
```

For example:

```
[[inputs.system]]
  load5
```

Then I run:

```
telegraf -config /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf -test
```

and see:

> 51Z E! [telegraf] Error running agent: Error parsing
>   /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf, toml: line 452: parse error

The github page has an example of the plugin's output I'm seeing the plugin as unconfigured in Chronograf when I start the daemon without the objectionable syntax.

User _telegraf is a member of the utmp system group. 
The inputs.mem and inputs.cpu are working properly.

Comment: In the web interface I see I can configure the plugin query. The default is "Dynamic source." If I hover over the ? icon it says, "The current source does not support Flux."

Answer (score 0):

The system plugin does not work on OpenBSD.